# Abort second job activity if first one aborts

Tags: datastage

I want abort 2nd job activity if 1st job activity aborts due env. issue or manual abortion.

I gone through the triggering option but couldn't get.
Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, You can't abort a job without running it.  So you would need to be able to invoke Job 2 with knowledge of Job 1 status (e.g. from activity variable Job1.$JobStatus).  This could be used to cause Job 2 to abort.

The cleanest solution would be a before-job subroutine, which sets its return code to 0 if Job 1's status was DSJS.RUNOK or DSJS.RUNWARN (these are DataStage constants), or to a non-zero value if Job 1's status was DSJS.RUNFATAL or any other value. This is the cleanest approach because the before-job subroutine could write a message to the job log indicating precisely why the job was being aborted.

A less clean way would be to have a parameter in Job 2 of type, say, Integer (anything other than string), and set its value in the Job Activity using an expression such as `If Job1.$JobStatus = DSJS.RUNFATAL Then "" Else 1` - setting a non-string parameter to "" will cause the job to abort with DSJE.PARAMBADVALUE error.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to show us exactly what you did. The use of trigger, which I explained earlier, is the correct solution.  If you did it correctly, the arrow on the design canvas should be red.

Comment: Hi Ray Wurlod , I have two job activities in the sequence job , i want abort second job activity if first job activity aborts.Earlier you explained to trigger second job activity if first job aborts.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could change your sequence to bypass Job 2 entirely, and instead simply log a message that Job 2 was being bypassed because Job 1 aborted.